# Parser Error Message: The file '/Site.master' does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

Evening folks!!

Stuck with this rather dull problem. I have deployed my website on my localhost (i.e. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebSite) but when i access it in the browser, I get this error message:

```
Parser Error Message: The file '/Site.master' does not exist.
```

It's weird coz the Site.Master is right there in the root folder. I have got 2 more folders in my website that have got a web.config each and i have converted these folders to applications from within the IIS. This error occurs when i access pages from these folders as well.

so the urls: http://localhost/mywebsite and http://localhost/mywebsite/mysubfolder, both have the aforementioned problem. And in both cases, the master page file does exist in the corresponding folders. I have checked the path of the MasterPageFile in my Default.aspx page and its "~/Site.Master" and the i can successfully run the web app from within Visual Studio (i.e. Cassini).

It would be really great if anyone can help me solve this mystery. Let me know if you need more info.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, the Default website in IIS was using the same port as the one that i created with a different host header. Stopping the Default website, then creating the website to point to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot and then converting the root website folder to an application and all the needed folders under it, fixed this problem. But how do you access i.e. what would be the URL for, a website that uses the same port but has a different host header defined? this still needs to be understood.

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to set the `mywebsite` folder as an application in IIS.

Comment: when i created a new website in IIS7, i selected the physical path to be the root folder of the website (i.e. mywebsite). this root folder contains all the pages and other sub-folders (2 of which, as i have pointed out, have been converted to applications). I would imagine that mywebsite is by default an application since its the root folder which contains Default.aspx and Site.Master. Did i understand you correctly?

Comment: i m sorry if that sounded confusing, in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot i have my deployed website i.e. a folder called "mywebsite" which contains all the pages, configs, masters etc. This is the root folder. When i "Add New Website" in IIS7, I point it to the above mentioned physical path i.e. C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite. Now, when i access it through the browser by requesting http://localhost/mywebsite, it gives me the said error. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Replace the tilde before `~/MasterPage.master` with a period `./MasterPage.master`.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="./MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Title="Untitled Page" %>
Line 2:
```

Comment: thanks mate! but I did manage to solve this myself about 2 years ago! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add an extra answer to this, in case it helps someone else in the future.

I had the same problem with an added Master page, which for some reason my site was refusing to acknowledge and publish (Blank.Master in my case, a name I've used many times).  Although I couldn't find the root cause of this problem, I WAS able to work around the issue by creating a new copy of the master file, naming it something different (Empty.Master), and changing the master page reference on the affected pages.

It's probably not a great solution, really, but I was on a deadline, and it at least allowed me to continue my work.